# Why is $! returning the wrong process ID for a subshell running in background?

Tags: shell, process, subshell

```
$(sleep 5) &
echo $!
sleep 1
echo "done"
```

The above outputs:

```
$ ./test.sh
7483
done
```

However if I search for `sleep` in `ps aux` I see:

```
 ps aux | rg sleep
chris     7484  0.0  0.0 132788  1432 pts/6    S+   12:10   0:00 sleep 1
chris     7485  0.0  0.0 132788  1432 pts/6    S+   12:10   0:00 sleep 5
chris     7519  0.0  0.0  10376  5744 pts/7    S+   12:10   0:00 rg --no-ignore-vcs sleep
```

The sleep 5 process is `7485` and not `7483` as output from the script. What is the cause of this behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$(sleep 5)
```

runs a shell which runs `sleep`. The pid given by `$!` is the shell’s.

You don’t need the substitution here,

```
 sleep 5 &
```

would give you `sleep`’s pid.

I imagine `sleep` in your example replaces something else, but in any case a background substitution is probably unnecessary. Using only a subshell,

```
(sleep 5) &
```

will typically give you `sleep`’s pid, because many shells replace themselves with the child command when they run the last command in a subshell, which effectively reuses the subshell’s pid for `sleep`; but

```
(sleep 5; sleep 5) &
```

will give you the shell’s pid, not `sleep`’s.